# Cannot select a date on mobile device using fullcalendarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have an issue with fullcalendarJS. My calendar works without problem in my desktop browser, However, when I test my app on my phone, I cannot select a date. When I tap the screen, nothing happen. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try check the console log from your phone browser?

Comment: Did you hold down your finger long enough? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/longPressDelay

Comment: No problem. Always read the manual! :-)